# Key assignments to associative array fail with the - sign without double quotes

Tags: syntax, autohotkey

```
for k, v in {font-weight : "bold"}
    msgbox %k% : %v%    ; : bold

for k, v in {"font-weight" : "bold"}
    msgbox %k% : %v%    ; font-weight : bold
```

Is this a bug or is a string passed as a key treated as an expression when the - sign is used? The manual says double quotes are optional though.

---

This is invalid causing the error. so now it makes sense.

```
font-value := "bold"
msgbox % font-value
```

Result:

> Line Text: font-value := "bold" Error: This line does not contain a
>   recognized action.

---

for additional notes:

```
for k, v in {font*weight : "bold"}
    msgbox %k% : %v%    ; : bold

for k, v in {10*2 : "10*2"}
    msgbox %k% : %v%    ; 20 : 10*2 

for k, v in { 0xeeeee : "0xeeeee"}
    msgbox %k% : %v%    ; 978670:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13397614/1074592), the minus sign is reserved.  The shortcut also wouldn't work when using any other operators.  The reason it isn't a bug is that it allows math, string manipulation, functions, etc. to be used in naming keys for objects.  It may or may not be a design flaw, but it works as intended by the developer.

From  [the AutoHotkey_L documentation](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/Objects.htm#Usage_Associative_Arrays):

> quote marks are optional **for keys
>   which consist only of word characters**. Any expression can be used as
>   a key, but to use a variable as a key, it must be enclosed in
>   parentheses. For example, `{(KeyVar): Value}` and `{GetKey(): Value}`
>   are both valid.

*(emphasis added)*

A word character typically means letters, numbers, and underscores.