# Cannot access font-weight property with DOM

Tags: dom, autohotkey

I'm having troubles accessing the font-weight property with DOM.

```
html =
(Ltrim
    <html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    #bar{
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    div {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body><div>foo</div><p id="bar">bar</p></body>
    </html>
)

doc := ComObjCreate("HTMLfile") 
doc.write(html)
msgbox % doc.styleSheets[0].rules[0].style.border           ; "black 1px solid"
msgbox % doc.styleSheets[0].rules[1].style.font-weight      ; nothing
msgbox % doc.styleSheets[0].rules[1].style["font-weight"]   ; "[object]"
```

Is this supposed to be this way? Or should the last two message boxes show the value "bold"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-` Minus sign is used in mathematical operations and cannot be used in a variable name, hence the error you are experiencing.

Try something like `Object.style.fontWeight="value"` as suggested at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_fontweight.asp